# How can I prevent my Animations from starting when the other animations are playing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to have an enemy attack the player and the enemy attacks through animation however the method I have to prevent the animation from starting when others are active are not working. The problem should be shown by [this](https://youtu.be/qSiYraXrNMI) (might be low quality). As you can see the problem is that it is turning the bools on and off continuously. I don't know why this is happening because the way I have it should work. Is there a way to block them from doing this and run one at a time that works? Here is my code:

Edit: I forgot to say this but I am not getting any errors with my code

```
public void AttackPlayer(GameObject playerPos, Animator anim, NavMeshAgent agent, GameObject self, bool MultiAttack, float inRange, float inView, float AttackRange, bool isBlocking, bool HasSeenPLayer)
    {
        distDif = Vector3.Distance(self.transform.position, playerPos.transform.position);

        if (distDif >= AttackRange)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(playerPos.transform.position);
            anim.SetBool("walk", false);
        }

        else if (distDif <= AttackRange)
        {
            anim.SetBool("walk", false);
        }

        MultAttack(playerPos, anim, agent, self, MultiAttack, inRange, inView);

        if (!MultiAttack)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Attack2", false);
            anim.SetBool("Attack3", false);
            StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack"));
        }

        if (!PlayerPos.FindPlayerPos(AttackRange, playerPos.transform, inView, self, HasSeenPLayer))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
            anim.SetBool("Attack2", false);
            anim.SetBool("Attack3", false);
            state = State.Chase;
        }
    }

    private bool noloop = true;

    public void MultAttack(GameObject playerPos, Animator anim, NavMeshAgent agent, GameObject self, bool MultiAttack, float inRange, float inView)
    {
        if (!MultiAttack) return;

        if (random == 0) random = Random.Range(1, 5);

        if (random == 1)
        {
            StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack"));
            random = 0;
            return;
        }

        if (random == 2)
        {
            if (HasParameter("Attack2", anim))
            {
                StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack2"));
                random = 0;
                return;
            }

            StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack"));
            random = 0;
            return;
        }

        if (random == 3)
        {
            if (HasParameter("Attack3", anim))
            {
                StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack3"));
                random = 0;
                return;
            }

            StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack"));
            random = 0;
            return;
        }

        if (random == 4)
        {
            BlockPlayer(playerPos, anim, agent, inRange, inView, self);
            random = 0;
            return;
        }

        StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack"));
        random = 0;
        return;

    }

    public static bool HasParameter(string paramName, Animator animator)
    {
        foreach (AnimatorControllerParameter param in animator.parameters)
        {
            if (param.name == paramName)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

 IEnumerator PlayAnim(Animator anim, string booleanName)
    {
        anim.SetBool(booleanName, true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length + anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime); 
        //^^^ this has a value I had debug.Log print the value and it has one value
        anim.SetBool(booleanName, false);
        
    }
```

Edit 2: This is how the attack function is called: (In its own script)

```
public void ChoseChasingWhatStateToAttackPlayer(NavMeshAgent agent, GameObject playerPos, GameObject Gself, Animator anim, bool MultiAttack, float inRange, float inView, float AttackRange, bool isBlocking, bool HasSeenPLayer)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case State.Chase:
                ChasePlayer(playerPos, Gself, anim, agent, AttackRange, inRange, inView, HasSeenPLayer);
                break;
            case State.Attack:
                AttackPlayer(playerPos, anim, agent, Gself, MultiAttack, inRange, inView, AttackRange, isBlocking, HasSeenPLayer);
                break;
            case State.Idle:
                IdlePlayer(playerPos, anim, agent, Gself, inRange, inView, HasSeenPLayer);
                break;
            case State.Wander:
                WanderPlayer(playerPos, anim, agent, Gself, HasSeenPLayer);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here it is in the main script:

```
TtF.ChoseChasingWhatStateToAttackPlayer(agent, Player_pos.player, self, anim, MultiAttack, inRange, inView, AttackRange, isBlocking, hasSeenPlayer);
// called in update
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your main problem may be that you are calling the `AttackPlayer()` function repeatedly. If this was the case (Edit: you updated the code and it looks like this IS the case), then it would call `MultAttack()` repeatedly which would cause it to choose a new random attack animation to play every time (possibly every frame).

I also see some minor problems that may be contributing but it's hard to tell:

> From your code:
>
> ```
> if (distDif >= AttackRange)
> {
>     agent.SetDestination(playerPos.transform.position);
>     anim.SetBool("walk", false);
> }
> ```

Do you really want to set the "walk" animation to false here?

Another:

> Your code:
>
> ```
> MultAttack(playerPos, anim, agent, self, MultiAttack, inRange, inView);
>
> if (!MultiAttack)
> {
>     anim.SetBool("Attack2", false);
>     anim.SetBool("Attack3", false);
>     StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack"));
> }
> ```

You are calling `MultAttack()` even when the variable `MultiAttack` is false. Instead of just "undoing" everything you do in `MultAttack()` if `MultiAttack` is false, maybe just don't call it unless `MultiAttack` is true? Like so:

```
if(MultiAttack)
{
    MultAttack(/*arguments here*/);
}
else
{
    //trigger single attack animation
}
```

I would also HIGHLY suggest passing all of that data though those functions as a single object or struct or something. That looks like the kind of data that should be stored on an "Enemy" object. Having all those parameters makes it really hard to tell what's happening and is hard to organize.

Comment: when you say that I should a "Enemy" object do you mean something like: `public struck Enemy
{
    public float health;
    public float speed;    
    public Enemy(float health, float speed)
    {
        this.health = health;
        this.speed = speed;        
    }
}` sorry if this is wrong I learnt about structs a while ago and I don't remember them that well

Comment: And you would initizale it like: `Enemy enemy1 = new Enemy(health, speed);'

Comment: Yes, but in this case using a class would be better. Structs are usually used for data types and classes for more "real" objects. I would suggest learning more about how OOP works in depth, it seems you may be lacking there. That, however, is a different question that you can find answers to elsewhere. Focus on fixing this problem first and then you can reorganize everything afterwards.